# Resonance condition in confocal cavity

Tags: optics, laser, resonance

In a confocal cavity, a beam traverses the length of the resonator 4 times between two transmissions along the same ray.

[image]
.

For example, in the above figure, path difference between two beams that get transmitted along beam 1 is an integral multiple of 4 times the cavity length. The same holds for transmission along ray 3. 
Therefore, the resonance condition is:
$4L=n\lambda$
which means $2L=n\frac{\lambda}{2}$ is the path difference between beams along ray 1 and ray 3, meaning that the beams along these rays are out of phase.

When the incident beam passes through the optical axis,rays 1 and 3 coincide, and destructively interfere for the previously derived resonance condition.

Does this mean that the resonance condition in a confocal cavity is different, depending on whether the incident beam is off-axis?

Comment: You've got a variation of a Fabry-Perot etalon here, so maybe reading the equations which apply to the F-P system will help clarify.

Comment: In all analyses of the confocal fabry-Perot arrangement, the resonance condition is taken to be $4L=n\lambda$. Does this modify to $2L=n\lambda$, when the output is focused to a point using a converging lens or when a beam passes along the principal axis?

Comment: @Chris If you know of some source where transmitted intensity from confocal fabry-perot is calculated, could you please let me know? I could find derivations only for the plane mirror case, and a similar analysis is not giving me the expected finesse.